# Trying to add jQuery validation without submit() button

Tags: jquery, html, validation

Below is my code. What I want to do is add validation so when the user clicks off an input field the validation message "name required" shows up. However at the minute it is just below the input field and is there all the time. Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  if($('#firstname').val() == ''){
    $('.errorMsg').show();
  } else{ 
    $('.errorMsg').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name"     maxlength="15"  <span class="errorMsg">Name required </span>
</input>
```

Comment: If this is for a real-world application, I would also advise against that `maxlength`-attribute. People tend to have more interesting names than most webdevelopers can imagine

Comment: @OliverBaumann But if the database only accepts 15, then it can cause some trouble. But I agree that 15 characters is a but low for a first name.

Comment: @Ivar, if a database only accepts 15 varchars, talk to the database admin ;-) honestly, that's not an argument. No offense meant, obviously!

Comment: @OliverBaumann Non taken. Only saying that using `maxlength` is not a bad thing per se. No matter how much you accept in the database, there is a limit somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `blur` event for that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#firstname').on('blur', function() {
        if ($('#firstname').val() == '') {
            $('.errorMsg').show();
        } else {
            $('.errorMsg').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name" 
   maxlength="15">  <span class="errorMsg" style="display: none;">Name required </span>
</input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to initially hide the error-message. You also have invalid HTML: the error-message `span` can't be nested in the input.

Working solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#firstname').on('blur', function() {
      if($(this).val() === '') {
        $('.errorMsg').show();
      } else {
        $('.errorMsg').hide();
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.errorMsg {
    display: none;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name" 
 maxlength="15"/>
 <span class="errorMsg">Name required </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `blur` event, which can be called directly from the found element using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.errorMsg').hide();

    $('#firstname').blur(function(){
    if($('#firstname').val() == ''){
        $('.errorMsg').show();
    }
        else{ 
            $('.errorMsg').hide();
        }

    });


});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjrtu1vq/)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) - Bind an event handler to the "blur" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Try ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wf1q60cc/))

```
var firstNameInput = $('input#firstname'),
    errorMsgEl = $('.errorMsg');

// Bind blur on the input for 'first name'
firstNameInput.bind('blur', function () {
    // Check if input is blank
    if(firstNameInput.val() == '') {
        // Ensure error isn't already displayed
        if (errorMsgEl.length == 0) $("<div class='errorMsg'>Name required</div>").insertAfter(this);
    } else {
        errorMsgEl.remove();
    }
});
```